# Multiple categories content labels in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I would like to display on my main page some articles, but only those that i like, not all of the articles. I could create new content type - like 'Main" to appear only on the main page, but it wouldn't be listed under articles. What I would like to do is to stick with articles content type, but assign a new label so I can display only these on the main page using views (by sorting by this new label). How can I do this? In Wordpress it's very easy, you just assign 2 categories, but in Drupal? Should I use taxonomy? If yes, how? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taxonomy is for organizing your content.  You can create either a fixed or fluid vocabulary list and attach it to your content type.  Content types are not limited as to the number of vocabulary lists that can be attached.

If you want a particular content type to only appear on the front page, than from the content type administration page (admin -> content management -> content types) set your work flow options to  be promoted to front page.  You can also just selectively choose which 'article' you want to appear by setting this option when you create the content.  No need for a vocabulary with this.

Views, of course, gives you much more power and flexibility.  I've used views and hidden vocabulary lists to filter content on several sites.  Very easy to do.